# Name files in a directory after other files in a different directory

Tags: linux, rename

I am on a GNU/Linux machine. I have a number of files in a directory `dir1` such as:

```
dir1/file_01.txt
dir1/file_02.txt
dir1/file_03.txt
dir1/file_04.txt
dir1/file_05.txt
```

Another directory `dir2` has other files such as:

```
dir2/text_01.txt
dir2/text_02.txt
dir2/text_03.txt
dir2/text_04.txt
dir2/text_05.txt
```

And I want to rename files in `dir2` to be `file_01.txt, ..., file_05.txt` such that `text_01.txt` is renamed `file_01.txt`, ..., `text_02.txt` is renamed `file_05.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

`mmv` should do what you need:

```
mmv dir2/text_*.txt dir2/file_#1.txt
```

Comment: So will this command "rename" all files in dir2 (text_*.txt) after their corresponding files in dir1 (file_*.txt) without changing files in dir1?

Comment: @FaizLotfy Yes it should. Please be carefull while testen

Comment: should it be: `mmv dir2/text_*.txt dir1/file_#1.txt`?